# Is there a way for spark to read this odd text format?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

The file format I have is sort of like csv and looks like this (abinitio .dat file of some sort):

```
1,apple,10.00,\n
2,banana,12.35,\n
3,orange,9.23,\n
```

The commas are actually "Start of Header" 0x01 byte characters, but I will use commas for simplicity. I can easily read the above sample by reading the file as a string RDD with a custom line split `,\n` and then passing that into `spark.read.csv`. I am currently splitting lines by `,\n` because there may be newlines in the data and I thought that those two characters were unique for each record. However a problem occurs when there are newline characters at the start of text fields. For example:

```
1,one \n apple,10.00,\n
2,two banana,12.35,\n
3,\n three orange,9.23,\n
```

My current code is able to ignore the newline in record `1` but picks up the `,\n` after the `3` and splits the 3 lines into 4. How can I reliably read in this format?
My current ideas are:

1. Check that there are the right number of `,` column delimiters before allowing a split. I am not sure how to implement this, is it possible to do a regex look-back when spark sees a `,\n` and check for the correct number of delimiters?
2. Try to coerce the file into some other format besides CSV
3. Make my own `InputFormatClass`, although I am not sure what this entails.